# java script button which changes an image when you hold down on button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button which when held down should change the picture next to it and then when you are not holding down on the button it will be on the original image. Now it comes up with the button and the image and knows that the picture of the button is a button but doesn't change the image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Joel's Button</title>
<script>
    var button=document.images["button"];
    function handleMDown()
    {
        document.getElementById("imagechange").src="red.jpg";
        return true
    }
    function handleMUp()
    {
        document.getElementById("imagechange").src="green.jpg";
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click in button</h1>
<a href="#"onmousedown="return handleMDown()" onmouseup="return handleMUp()">
<img id="button" src="http://goo.gl/VqDdz0" width="220" height="220"  
  border="0" alt="javascript button" onmousedown="return handleMDown()" 
  onmouseup="return handleMUp"></a>
<img id="imagechange" src="green.jpg"width="220" height=" 220" alt="image">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it have to be pure JS or are you fine working with jQuery as well?

Comment: syntax error: missing variable name:
var =document.images["http://goo.gl/jjOUxT"]

Comment: thank you so much , i forgot to take that out

Comment: @Woli123 You should mark the correct answer for better orientation.

Comment: Why not use css? You can use the `:active` pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the thing:

First of all, as mentioned by Petr Felzmann

> syntax error: missing variable name: var =document.images["goo.gl/jjOUxT"]

Second of all, in your `onmousedown` & `onmouseup` events you can call the function by going `handleMDown();` or `handleMUp();` instead of your `return handleMDown()`.

Last but not least, I've changed the images around a bit, this is just so I could test it properly, but from what I understood this is what you basically wanted:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>Click in button</h1>
    <a href="#"onmousedown="handleMDown();" onmouseup="handleMUp();"> 
    <!-- Changed the onmousedown & onmouseup to handleMDown(); or handleMUp(); accordingly -->
    <img id="button" src="http://doha.biz/wp-content/uploads/awpcp/1276329896_0.jpg" width="220" height="220" border="0" alt="javascript button" onmousedown="handleMDown();" onmouseup="handleMUp();"></a>
    <!-- Changed the onmousedown & onmouseup to handelMDown(); or handleMUp(); accordingly -->
    <img id="imagechange" src="http://doha.biz/wp-content/uploads/awpcp/1276329896_0.jpg" width="220" height=" 220" alt="image">
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function handleMDown() {
    document.getElementById("imagechange").src="http://www.veryst.com/_Images/Material%20Testing%20--%20Modeling%20Services/Small%20punch%201.png";
    return true
}
function handleMUp()
{
    document.getElementById("imagechange").src="http://doha.biz/wp-content/uploads/awpcp/1276329896_0.jpg" ;
    return true;
}
```

**Don't forget to change the images back in the Javascript as well as in the HTML**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you should put script tag in before close body tag :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Click in button</h1>
    <a href="#" onmousedown="handleMDown()" onmouseup="handleMUp()">
        <img id="button" src="http://goo.gl/VqDdz0" width="220" height="220" border="0" alt="javascript button" onmousedown="handleMDown()" onmouseup="handleMUp">
    </a>
    <img id="imagechange" src="green.jpg" width="220" height=" 220" alt="image">
    <script>
    var button= document.images["button"];



    var e =document.images["http://goo.gl/jjOUxT"]

    function handleMDown()
    {document.getElementById("imagechange").src="red.jpg";

    return true
    }
    function handleMUp()
    {
        document.getElementById("imagechange").src="green.jpg" ;
        return true;
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried too much, you can do it much simpler. I stripped it down to the bare minimum: changing the images on the right of the big red button. I stripped the link, too, just add it back if you need it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Joel's Button</title>
<script>
function handleMDown()
{
  document.getElementById("imagechange").src="red.jpg";
}
function handleMUp()
{
  document.getElementById("imagechange").src="green.jpg" ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click in button</h1>
<img id="button" src="http://goo.gl/VqDdz0" width="220" height="220"  
 border="0" alt="javascript button" onmousedown="handleMDown()" 
 onmouseup="handleMUp()">
<img id="imagechange" src="green.jpg"width="220" height=" 220" alt="image">
</body>
</html>
```

The event-handler (the `onthingy` attributes if you excuse my simplifying) do not make use of any return of the functions they call, they just call them. If you want to call functions (`function fun(){...})` you need to add `()` at the end of the function name, you forgot that in one places.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` to handle these events

```
document.getElementById('red').onmousedown = function () {
    document.getElementById('red').style.backgroundColor = 'red';  
};

document.getElementById('red').onmouseup = function () {
    document.getElementById('red').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kdyr8owk/

Answer (score 0):

**Change your HTML code to:**

```
<img id="button" src="http://goo.gl/VqDdz0" style="width: 220px; height: 220px; border: 0;" alt="javascript button" onmousedown="handleMDown()" onmouseup="handleMUp()">
<img id="imagechange" src="put your NOT holding button down source here" alt="image" style="width: 220px; height: 220px;">
```

Note that I changed your HTML code to match today's standard of using CSS to style elements.

**Change your JavaScript code to:**

```
function handleMDown() {
    document.getElementById("imagechange").src="put your holding button down source here";
}

function handleMUp()
{
    document.getElementById("imagechange").src="put your NOT holding button down source here";
}
```

Check out fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bspcr00t/2/).